# Postgres taking backup of master data and schema for few of the tables

Tags: postgresql

In my database, I have the master tables starting with m_* and other. What I want to take the back of tables with following scenario.

1. Backup schema + data for master tables i.e table names starting with m_*
2. Backuo schema structure for the rest of the tables.

I did read the following command somewhere

```
pg_dump -U "postgres" -h "local" -p "5432" 
    -d dbName -F c -b -v -f c:\uti\backup.dmp
    --exclude-table-data '*.table_name_pattern_*'
    --exclude-table-data 'some_schema.another_*_pattern_*'
```

But I have so many tables and I find it tedious to put each table name in it. Any tidy way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linux:

File `foo.sh` (adjust filtering conditions):

```
psql <connection and other parameters> -c "copy (select format('--exclude-table-data=%s.%s', schemaname, tablename) from pg_tables where schemaname in ('public', 'foo') and tablename<>'t') to stdout;"
```

Command (note about backticks):

```
pg_dump <connection and other parameters> `./foo.sh`
```

Note that it is very flexible approach.